# Liberty Exception SSLv3

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Anyone explain to me how can fix this problem on liberty 20.0.0.12

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKO0801E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired. Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Client requested protocol SSLv3 is not enabled or supported in server context
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.negotiateProtocol(ClientHello.java:880)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:832)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:810)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:450)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1078)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1065)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1012)
        at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:751)
        at [internal classes]
.
```

I search in internet but can not found solution to fix this problem !
Question 1) this exception is for Liberty engine or my JaxRS Client request ?

```
@Singleton
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class BinanceService {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @EJB
    private StatisticDAO statisticDAO;

    private Client client;
    private WebTarget target;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getDefault();
            SSLParameters sslParameters = sc.getSupportedSSLParameters();
            sslParameters.setProtocols(new String[]{"SSLv1.2", "SSLv3"});

            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = {new InsecureTrustManager()};
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new InsecureHostnameVerifier();

            client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sc).hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid).build();
            target = client.target("https://api.binance.com");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<String> exchangeInfo() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Response response = target.path("/api/v3/exchangeInfo")
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .get();
            JsonObject jsonObject = response.readEntity(JsonObject.class);
            JsonArray symbolsArray = jsonObject.get("symbols").asJsonArray();
            for (JsonValue symbolJson : symbolsArray) {
                String symbol = symbolJson.asJsonObject().getString("symbol");
                String baseAsset = symbolJson.asJsonObject().getString("baseAsset");
                if (baseAsset.endsWith("DOWN") || baseAsset.endsWith("UP")) {
                    continue;
                }
                String finaSymbolName = baseAsset + "/" + symbol.substring(baseAsset.length());
                list.add(finaSymbolName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.finer("Failed to fetch binance symbols");
        }
        return list;
    }

    public void fetchAndSaveAllSymbols() {
        List<String> list = exchangeInfo();
        logger.info(String.format("fetch and save %d symbols", list.size()));
        statisticDAO.bulkInsert(list);
    }
}
```

**Note:** I manually generated PKCS12 :

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias "cs-key" -keystore "cs.jks" -dname "CN=test.local" -keyalg RSA -storepass "mah123456"  -validity 365 
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cs.jks -srcstorepass "mah123456" -destkeystore key.p12 -deststorepass "mah123456" -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Question 2: How can fix this ?

Comment: SSLv3 has been completely broken and totally insecure for 7 years, and is no longer supported by any decent systems or admins. It doesn't look to me like that code talks to your server at all but if it does replace your defective `setProtocols` with at least `TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` (available since j7) and preferably add `,TLSv1.3` (since j11), or better yet let it default so the JVM uses best available protocol. PS: Since you are clearly on j>=9 `keytool` already creates PKCS12 by default, not JKS, and there is no need to do any conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servers Java SDK likely/smartly blocks the antiquated SSLv3 via jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in java.security.  Either modernize your SSL client or allow the unsafe SSLv3 in the server in java.security.